# Get git like option completion in python program

Tags: python, git, shell

When I type

```
$ git br<tab>
```

Git automatically completes the option into this:

```
$ git branch
```

Suppose I want to imitate this functionality in my fictitious program `say.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

args = ['morning', 'night']

if sys.argv[1] == args[0]:
    print "Mr. Tacha Vinci! Good morning!"
elif sys.argv[1] == args[1]:
    print "Mr. Tacha Vinci, sweet dreams..."
```

Such that when I do:

```
$ say.py mor<tab>
```

I get:

```
$ say.py morning
```

Comment: http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#completion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not Git that does the completion, it's your shell -- most probably Bash, and specifically by way of [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html). (The link is to the Python bindings for this library, which is what you would use to provide completion inside a running Python program. To create Bash completions, look at e.g. [the ABS intro](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html).)

Comment: So the solution is shell specific and not python specific. Is there no way to avoid writing shell functions? I find them ugly :)

Comment: Hire someone? My fee probably exceeds your budget, though.

Comment: So you are saying that it can be done given enough money, and that I don't have enough money to get it done? I fail to grasp the motive behind (or the mood of) that comment. Anyway thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.